# How to force 'cron_schedules' every minute instead 1 hour?

Tags: wp-cron, cron

I have a problem because I try to run my function every minute...

And there are my two codes which I tried:

```
function my_cron_schedules($schedules){
    if(!isset($schedules["61sec"])){
        $schedules["61sec"] = array(
            'interval' => 61,
            'display' => __('Every 61 sec'));
    }
    return $schedules;
}
add_filter('cron_schedules','my_cron_schedules');
 
add_action('wp','setup_schedule');
function setup_schedule() {
  if (!wp_next_scheduled('expire_ogl') ) {
    wp_schedule_event( current_time('timestamp'), '61sek' , 'expire_ogl');
  }
}

add_action( 'expire_ogl', 'expire_ogl_now' );
function expire_ogl_now() {
update_post_meta(1,'now',date());
}
```

I tried to do also this:

```
add_action('wp','setup_schedule');
    function setup_schedule() {
      if (!wp_next_scheduled('expire_ogl') ) {
        wp_schedule_event( current_time('timestamp'), 'every_minute' , 'expire_ogl');
      }
    }
    
    add_action( 'expire_ogl', 'expire_ogl_now' );
    function expire_ogl_now() {
    update_post_meta(1,'now',date());
    }
```

But when I check planned schedules - I get always that it will be runed every hour (even If I set '61sec' or 'every_minute'. Can somone help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's incomplete and OP requested deletion.

Answer (score 3):

You have the wrong period alias in your code

You added your personal period in `my_cron_schedules()` as `61sec`:

```php
$schedules["61sec"] = array(
```

but use it in `setup_schedule()` as `61sek`:

```php
wp_schedule_event( current_time('timestamp'), '61sek' , 'expire_ogl');
```

The other parts of the code look right.

Comment: Actually, that needs to be a semicolon, not a comma - as it indicates the end of the array deceleration.